# Webpack resolve.alias does not work with typescript?

Tags: typescript, webpack

I try to shorten my imports in typescript

from `import {Hello} from "./components/Hello";`

to `import {Hello} from "Hello";`

For that I found out you can use `resolve.alias` in webpack thus I configured that part as following

```
resolve: {
    root: path.resolve(__dirname),
    alias: {
        Hello: "src/components/Hello"
    },
    extensions: ["", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
},
```

Webpack builds, and the output bundle.js works. However typescript's intellisense complain it `cannot find the module`

So my question is whether or not webpack's resolve.alias works with typescript?

I found following [issue](https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader/issues/34) but there's no answer to it.

Comment: Quick link for newcomers in 2022: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69323871/5290519

Answer (score 104, accepted):

If you're using `ts-loader`, you might have to synchronize your webpack `alias`/`resolve` settings with your `paths` setting in your `tsconfig.json`.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "Hello": ["src/components/Hello"]
        }
    }
}
```

If you're using `awesome-typescript-loader`, then webpack can figure this out automatically from the `paths` setting in your `tsconfig.json`, as per [the status on this issue from the repo](https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader/issues/156). That way, you don't need to duplicate the same information in your Webpack `alias` field.

Comment: Seems like I need to set the `paths` property also when I'm using `awesome-typescript-loader`. I'm using webpack1, and awesome-typescript-loader 1.1.1. But it works though :)

Comment: This has gotten me for a second time now.. make sure you set the baseUrl if you're setting paths. You need both.

Comment: new project with angular cli, adding app/components folder, moving the app.comonent under it in its own folder. tscinfig: adding baseUrl:"." and paths:{"~c": ["src/app/components"]} (c as components). adding index.d.ts with export "./app.component/app.component". npm install awesome-typescript-loader. vs code can resolve import {AppComponent} from "~c"; (mouse hover shows the correct path). ng build -> ERROR in C:/Temp/a4-cli-test/src/app/app.module.ts (4,30): Cannot find module '~c'.
Did I miss something?

Comment: FWIW, I couldn't get this to work just when using the `TsConfigPathsPlugin ` [as documented on awesome-typescript-loader's README](https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader#advanced-path-resolution-in-typescript-20), but synchronizing the config just like ts-loader seemed to work.

Comment: This solved my problem: we were using a custom module syntax which defined aliases to files other than `index`. Renaming the files and fixing the aliases got the paths working. Thanks!

Comment: but what if I have a dynamic alias?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue but It seems like I have everything you suggested.  Any advice https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51624134/aliasing-with-webpack-4-and-awesome-typescript-loader-not-working

Comment: Also when you look at the bundle.js would you expect to see the alias in there or would you expect it to be converted to the mappings?

Comment: To anyone trying to make this work with javascript files, you need to add the configuration to ` jsconfig.json` instead of `tsconfig.json`

Answer (score 94):

You are missing one very important point in `tsconfig.json`:
The matching pattern!

It should be configured like this:

```
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": {
    "appSrc/*": [
        "src/*"
    ]
 }
```

The "*" is the important part to tell TS to match anything on the right side.

I found that out from this article: [Type-safe es2015 module import path aliasing with Webpack, Typescript and Jest](https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/type-safe-es2015-module-import-path-aliasing-with-webpack-typescript-and-jest-fe461347e010)

**NOTE**

- Make sure all your `webpack.config.js` are updated (e.g. if you use
  storybook).
- If you use Visual Studio Code you may need to restart it,
  in order for the squiggly lines to disappear.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. My IDE also required this to pick up autocompletion.

Comment: I had to restart VSCode once for the change to take effect.

Comment: Can confirm that this helped me more than the accepted answer, as I have directories as aliases.

Comment: This immediately fixed everything for me in VS Code, should be the accepted answer

Comment: doesn´t work for me. @Daniel Rosenwasser´s answer did work tho

Comment: Fixed the problem immediately as is. One caveat is that it didn't like that my alias case didn't match the directory case, so I changed that to match

Answer (score 44):

As others have mentioned, you need to provide an `alias` in your webpack.config.js:

```
    resolve: { 

        extensions: [".ts", ".js"],
        alias: {
            forms: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/forms/")
        } 
    },
```

This needs to be in synch with your `tsconfig.json` file (baseUrl and paths are required).

```
"compilerOptions":  {
    baseUrl: "./",
    ...
    paths: {
       "forms/*": ["src/forms/*"]
    }
}
```

Note: The wildcard pattern is necessary to match with your resolve alias configuration.

Then you can import any library using your alias:

```
import { FormsModule } from "forms/my-forms/my-forms.module";
```

Comment: Is there a way to configure webpack to also support it without tha slash `"~*": ["src/*"]` which is supported by TS (tsconfig.json) and VSCode? The result is `import x from '~components/x` which translates to `src/components/x`.

Comment: This is the only solution that works for me. Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me: Webpack 4.35.2 and Typescript 2.8 and AT-Loader 5.0

Comment: Worked for me, also check this out if you're getting related build errors for node_modules dependencies: https://github.com/netlify/netlify-lambda/issues/179#issuecomment-531468792

Answer (score 13):

You can also configure [`tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin) in order not to duplicate your aliases in several places. It will pick up aliases from `tsconfig.json` file and automatically add them to webpack.

Comment: This should be the #1 answer if using webpack. Thanks man

Answer (score 12):

If anyone still have this issue, don't forget to add your folder to the "include" option on tsconfig.json like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "outDir": "./built/",
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*",
    "./tests/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had to make a small adjustment to Caio Saldanha's solution to make it work in my environment.

I am using Babel 7 with `babel-plugin-module-resolver` to resolve aliases. No `ts-loader` or `awesome-typescript-loader` as Babel 7 supports TypeScript out of the box using `@babel/preset-typescript`. I had to add an extra path configuration for each alias to load the module root (e.g. `index.ts`) automagically:

```
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": {  // this must be synchronized with .babelrc.js's module-resolver alias config
    "component": ["src/component/index.ts"],
    "component/*": ["src/component/*"],
    ...
}
```

Having an `index.ts` in the `/component` folder with the following content:

```
export { default as Logo } from './Logo';
```

Without the extra `.../index.ts` line this import didn't work for me:

```
import { Logo } from 'component';
```

Alias config in `.babelrc.js`:

```
plugins: [
[
    'module-resolver',
    {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
        root: ['./src'],
        alias: {
        // this must be synchronized with tsconfig.json's path configuration
            component: './src/component',
        },
    },
],
```

Comment: Hi @AMilassin do you can confirm that you didn't use ts-loader in your project with babel? thank you.

Comment: I have ts-loader with webpack for compilation and tsc for type checking configured.

Comment: @kalwalt: you don't need ts-loader upon babel 7

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 cases

1. **When you write custom webpack** It works with typescript but not directly. To explain, there are 2 types of compilation happening in backstage. First tsx -> js for which tsconfig.json plays the role, but when you actually compile the js code then webpack comes into picture. 
   So for aliases, resolve should be placed at both places i.e in tsconfig and webpack to successfully run the application
2. **when you use default(after create react app)**: You just need to add `"baseUrl": "./src"` in tsconfig and see the code work.

Answer (score 1):

It's not good practice to use alias for just 1 particular component and you should tell to webpack config that you have existing aliases setup in my ts-config by using [tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin), here is the sample config

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  ...
  resolve: {
    plugins: [new TsconfigPathsPlugin({/* options: see below */})]
  }
  ...
}
```

```
//ts-config.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "components/*": "components/*"
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

and **second** solution, you might as well manual resolve the issue by specifying the aliases what you want in `webpack.config`, but if you don't want, you may follow the above config

```
// webpack.config.js
module.export = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'components': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components')
    }
  }
}
```

remember the role of `tsconfig` or `jsconfig` is to provide an intellisense to your editor and give direction to your bundler

```
//ts-config.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "components/*": "components/*"
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

either what solution you chose, you should still use it as this

```
import {Home} from 'components';
...
```

and if you are out of your curiosity how `webpack.config` rely on your `tsconfig.json`, you may read [ts-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-loader)

Answer (score -3):

I *think* you can do this and have it work the way you describe:

```
resolve: {
    root: [
        path.resolve(__dirname),
        <path_to_components_directory> //e.g. path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'components')
    ], 
    extensions: ["", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
},
```

Then you can do `import {Hello} from "Hello";`

I know I do this to resolve file paths in my `src/js` directory. I am not using typescript though, but I don't think it would affect the result.

Comment: but typescript is the problem here