# Typescipt fails to recognize webpack resolve.alias

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack

This is in my `Webpack` config:

```
usersAlias: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/pages/users'),
```

This is in my `tsconfig.json`:

```
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": {
  "usersAlias/*": ["src/pages/users/*"],
}
```

This is the code hierarchy:

[image: solution]

This is my usage in `Àpp.js`:

```
import Users from 'usersAlias/Users';
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
Cannot find module 'usersAlias/Users'.ts(2307)
```

**If I change `Àpp.tsx` to `App.js` Everything works! My issue is `TypeScript` related.**

**UPDATE**

My Full `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "baseUrl": ".",
  "paths": {
    "usersAlias/*": ["src/pages/users/*"],
  }
}
```

Comment: And there is a `src/pages/users/Users.ts`? (It's not expanded in your screenshot)

Comment: @Sydney Y yes of course

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you dont need the ...

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      users: path.resolve(__dirname, '/src/pages/users'),
    }
  }
};
```

And in your code

```
import Users from 'users';
```

Check config [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias)

Comment: not working, webpack recognizes the alias and working without typescript in my example. My propblem is typescript related

Comment: updated, basically its the RCA tsconfig after I ejected

Comment: And did you already config for tsx and ts extension to resolve in webpack ?

Comment: yes, this is RCA project, I am working successfully with tsx

Comment: Can you share your code on github so I can take a look at ?

Comment: Sorry I try with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40443806/webpack-resolve-alias-does-not-work-with-typescript) but still not work