# Can not import file with "@" in typescript

Tags: typescript, webpack

webpack resolve setted like this

```
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/')
        },
        extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ]
    }
```

How to make this work in typescript

[image]

Comment: Do these answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601592/typescript-import-path-alias and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40443806/webpack-resolve-alias-does-not-work-with-typescript

Comment: the code compiled well, but Vscode still has error warning

Answer (score 0):

The following steps solved my problem:

1. Set paths in tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     "paths": {
        "@/*": ["./src/*"]
     }
  }
}
```

2. Ctrl + Shift + P > TypeScript: Restart Ts server